# Active an extension based on condition in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

Hi i have 2 payment method available in my magento2 store . One is cash on delivery and other is custom payment gateway . I install custom payment gateway extension and it is working fine .

Now i have some conditions if that condition is ok then only i need to make active that custom payment gateway extension .

> My products have a product attribute called 'otherthancod' . If
> 'otherthancod' is active then only show the custom
> payment gateway in checkout page. For that i write the following code .

```
        $items = $cart->getItems();
        $flag = 0;
        $count=0;
        foreach($items as $item){
            
            $attribute1 = $item->getProduct()->getData('otherthancod');
             if($attribute1){
                $flag++;
                $count++;
            }else{
                $flag--;
            }
        }
        
        if($flag == $count){
                    $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
                    $checkResult->setData('is_available', true); 
        }else{
                    $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
                    $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); 
        }
```

Now i want to know **where i need to put this code** ? I don't want to create another extension for that .

Please help.

In my custom payment extension i have seen the following page
**app/code/custompaymentgaetway/custom/Gateway/Config/config.php**

```
class Config extends \Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\Config{
 

}
```

**can i add if condition before this class ?** I think this class is activating payment gateway .

I can see that in frontend template of my payment gateway is
**\view\frontend\web\template\custompaymentgaetway.html**. Actually i want to hide this frontend once the condition is false .

Comment: what do you mean by hiding extension?

Comment: in checkout page i can see cash on delivery and custom payment gateway . If the condition is false then i need to hide the custom payment gateway from checkout page . Could you please help to solve this .

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/disable-payment-method-programmatically-magento2/ see this

Comment: thank you very much . But this code  need to write in  app/code/ folder . So after that i have to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade .  I am too much worried abi=out running this command . Than's why i don't want to create an other extension . Can i add this code in any other installed extension?

Comment: why you are worried about  setup:upgrade command? it is OOTB command and it should work fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217293/discussion-between-abilash-er-and-keyur-shah).

Comment: ok added, please write magento question on https://magento.stackexchange.com/ as you will find more number of peoples of magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not afraid of `setup:upgrade` command as it is OOTB Magento command it should work fine, and If something break then please fix it might be some permission issue on server side

First you will need to create `events.xml` file under `app/code/Company/Module/etc/.` Then write `“payment_method_is_active”` event in it. This is the event that hits on the checkout page for payment method availability.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="custom_payment" instance="Company\Module\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now create `PaymentMethodAvailable.php` under `Company/Module/Observer/` and write the following code in the file. I am disabling the check money order payment method, you can change the payment method code according to your need.

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * payment_method_is_active event handler.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // you can replace "checkmo" with your required payment method code
        if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="checkmo"){
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); //this is disabling the payment method at checkout page
        }
    }
}
```

Now the payment method Check Money Order is disabled from checkout page .

For reference please check [this](https://webkul.com/blog/disable-payment-method-programmatically-magento2/) link

Answer (score 2):

Don't hesitate to create your own module in `app/code/YourNamespace`.

Basically you just need a `registration.php` file and an `etc/module.xml`:

https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/

---

Also see the following example showing how to declare the Observer for this event:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/188367/27460

Comment: i have to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade . I am too much worried about running this command . Than's why i don't want to create an other extension . Can i add this code in any other installed extension?

Comment: You could add it to another module of your own, if you already have some in `app/code`. Don't add it to a third-party extension, or you will get in trouble when you update it.

Comment: You will probably have to run `setup:upgrade` at one point, though ;) So, I would recommend trying it on a local version (not your server). Backup the database first if you're worried.